# Multivariate distribution of linear regression coefficients and unbiased variance estimator

Tags: regression, unbiased-estimator

### Excerpt from "Elements of Statistical Learning", p.47

Assume that the conditional expectation of $Y$ is linear in $X_1, \ldots, X_p$. Also assume that the deviations of $Y$ around its expectation are additive and Gaussian. Hence $$Y = E(Y \mid X_1, \ldots, X_p) + \varepsilon,$$ $$ = \beta_0 + \sum_{j = 1}^p X_j \beta_j + \varepsilon,$$ where the error $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is a Gaussian random variable.

It is then easy to show that $\hat \beta \sim N(\beta, (X^t X)^{-1} \sigma^2)$ (1) and that $(N - p - 1)\hat \sigma^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{N-p-1}$ (2).

Earlier they also assume that the observations $y_i$ are uncorrelated and have constant variance $\sigma^2$, and the $x_i$ are fixed.

---

### Question

This part of ESL is repetition of basics that I'm trying to rehash since it was a long time ago that I studied this stuff.

For (1) I can show that $\mathrm{Cov}(\hat \beta) = (X^t X)^{-1} \sigma^2$ and of course $E(\hat \beta) = \beta$, but don't I need to know that $Y$ is normally distributed to be able to tell the distribution of $\hat \beta \sim N(E(\hat \beta), \mathrm{Cov}(\hat \beta))$?

For (2) I know that the hat matrix $X(X^t X)^{-1}X^t$ is idempotent, has rank $p + 1$ and $X^t \varepsilon = 0$. How can I finish (2)?

Comment: More rigorously, it means $\hat{\beta} | X \sim N(\beta, (X^TX)^{-1}\sigma^2)$ and $(N - p - 1)\hat{\sigma}^2 | X \sim \sigma^2\chi_{N - p - 1}^2$. That is, these are conditional distributions instead of marginal distributions.

Comment: That makes sense. Here we can assume that the $x_i$ are fixed/deterministic.

Comment: Note that the book also mentioned that "*$x_i$ are fixed (non random)*".  In this case, the conditional distributions coincide marginal distributions.  If you still have difficulty to derive them, I can post an answer.

Comment: I have trouble knowing how I can assume that $\hat \beta$ is normally distributed. I do know its expectation and covariance matrix.

As for the second question I assume it has something to do with $X(X^tX)^{-1}X^t$ being a projection matrix hence splitting $N$ into the projection which has dimension $p + 1$ and the rest which is of dimension $N - (p + 1)$, however I can't seem to hammer down the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normality of $\hat{\beta}$ follows from the fact that [any affine transformation of a normal random vector is still normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation).  Here, in matrix form, $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y = \beta + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon$ is an affine transformation of the $N$-dimensional random vector $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_{(N)})$. Hence the first result.

The second one regards the distribution of the residual vector
$$\hat{\epsilon} = (I_{(N)} - H)Y = (I_{(N)} - H)(X\beta + \epsilon) = (I_{(N)} - H)\epsilon,$$

where $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$.

Since $(N - p - 1)\hat{\sigma}^2 = \hat{\epsilon}'\hat{\epsilon} = \epsilon'(I_{(N)} - H)\epsilon$, $\sigma^{-1}\epsilon \sim N(0, I_{(N)})$, the second result follows from the distribution of quadratic form of multivariate normal random vectors (see, for example, Theorem 1.4.2 in *Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory* by R. Muirhead).

---

For your convenience (and also because of the importance of this theorem), I copy it here:

> *If $X$ is $N_m(\mu, I_m)$ and $B$ is an $m \times m$ symmetric matrix then $X'BX$ has a noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution if and only if $B$ is idempotent, in which case the degrees of freedom and the noncentrality parameter are respectively $k = \operatorname{rank}(B) = \operatorname{tr}(B)$ and $\delta = \mu'B\mu$.*

The idea of the proof is that $B$ has the canonical form $B = H\operatorname{diag}(I_{(k)}, 0)H'$ with $H$ orthogonal when $B$ is idempotent and rank $k$. The closedness of multivariate normal distribution under the affine transformation again plays a role here.