# Linear Regression - Proof that coefficients estimated via OLS follow a normal distribution

Tags: regression, least-squares, central-limit-theorem, sampling-distribution

The aim of my question can be better illustrated by this quote extracted from the third chapter of Elements of Statistical Learning ([link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-84858-7) to book):
[image: Quote from ESTL book]

**I'm trying to understand why, given that the error term follows a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and constant and finite variance, do the coefficients also follow a Gaussian**.

I understand how to derive the expected values of the beta estimate as well as its variance. I'm only having trouble proving its sampling distribution (the Normal).

Also (and please let me know if I should be asking this question in a new post)

- **how would the sampling distribution of the beta estimates be affected if the error term is not normally distributed - would they, for example, also tend to follow a normal distribution if our sample size is sufficiently large, under the CLT?**

Comment: this is often inspected visually using a qq plot. Shapiro-Wilk can test it formally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: test normality of residuals of linear model - which residuals to use](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118214/r-test-normality-of-residuals-of-linear-model-which-residuals-to-use)

Comment: basically because a linear function of a gaussian variable is also gaussian (we condition on distribution of X/assume X is deterministic). why don't you add the formula for the coefficients to your question, substituting in the definition of Y, ie 3.9.

Comment: you are better off reading another book on OLS. ESL basically just reviews the results for OLS.

Comment: $\varepsilon$ has a Normal distribution and linear combinations of Normal variables are Normal.  This will be true even with just a single observation -- it has nothing to do with the CLT.  BTW, *all* Gaussian distributions have finite variance.

Comment: @seanv507 that is exactly my question! I do understand the intuition behind what you are saying but was hoping for a more theoretical approach. I believe I found it already looking at the post I've linked on my comment to the answer of Demetri Pananos

Comment: @Xi'an I think a better duplicate, covering *exactly the same excerpt from the same book* (!) is [Multivariate distribution of linear regression coefficients and unbiased variance estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601268/multivariate-distribution-of-linear-regression-coefficients-and-unbiased-varianc)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting almost verbatim from Wooldridge...

Under the assumptions of the classical linear model (namely, that the errors are gaussian with mean 0 and finite variance), each of the estimated coefficients can be written as

$$ \hat{\beta}_j = \beta_j + \sum_{i=1}^n w_{i, j}u_i$$

where $w_{i, j} = \hat{r}_{i,j}/SSR_j$ is the ratio between the ith residual from the regression of $x_j$ onto the other variances and the sum of swaured residuals from said regression. Because the $wz$ depend only on the independent variables, we can treat them as nonrandom and observe the estimated coefficients are linear combinations of iid gaussians.  Since, by assumption, the $u$ were iid Gaussian, so to is the estimated coefficient.

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look at it! In the meantime I also found a [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601268/multivariate-distribution-of-linear-regression-coefficients-and-unbiased-varianc?rq=1) that mostly answers my question (this post question did not pop up in the 'possibly related' section when writing a new post). It talks about [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of multivariate normal distributions